# python selenium click on a link button

Tags: python, selenium, click

I am quite new to python selenium and I am trying to click on a button which has the following html structure:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadCalendarsForDateFn('jmpto1605')"><span class="jumpToMonthMM">May</span><span class="jumpToMonthYY">2016</span></a><br/>
```

I would like to be able to click the "May 2016" button above. Can someone guide me how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check both month and year with an XPath:

```
//a[span[@class="jumpToMonthMM"] = "May" and
    span[@class="jumpToMonthYY"] = "2016"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the link button! One followup question is when I issue the click() command, it just didn't jump to the May 2016. 

`elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[span[@class="jumpToMonthMM"] = "May" and span[@class="jumpToMonthYY"] = "2016"]')`
`print('Found It!')`
`elem.click()`

Comment: @damingzi great! Do you mean nothing happens when you issue a `click()`? What if you would [move to the element and then click](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains): `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem).click().perform()`? Don't forget the import: `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous replies. But the ActionChains click didn't work neither. I am thinking if the elem "May 2016" is the correct one to click. Do you have any clue?

Comment: @damingzi could you please elaborate this problem into a separate question? This might make more sense since more people may help. Make sure to provide all the necessary details. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I found a workaround for click(). I substituted .click() with .send_keys("\n"), the latter one does almost the same thing :)

Comment: Would you be so kind to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435984/radio-button-does-not-get-clicked-in-selenium-python ?

Answer (score 1):

Alexce has a good solution but you could also  look for the onclick attribute with `loadCalendarsForDateFn('jmpto1605')`:

```
find_element_by_xpath("""//a[@onclick ="loadCalendarsForDateFn('jmpto1605')"]""")
```

The 05 and 16 obviously correspond to May and 2016 as so I think it is safe to assume it is unique.

Comment: Thank you Padraic for your input :) I tried similar approach below, and it also worked!

`find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@onclick, 'jmpto1605')]")`