# Radio button does not get clicked in Selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium

Folks, this is driving me crazy. I have snippets like the following

```
<label class="" for="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1">
    <input id="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_B1" name="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT" value="B1" aria-describedby="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT_error_0" aria-invalid="true" data-clipboard="M37_Q_POSWECHSEL_BETT#B1" type="radio">
    0
</label>
```

Here, I'd like to select the radio buttons and select them with the following code:

```
radios = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'M37_Q_')][@value='B1']")
for radio in radios:
    # just check the id
    print(radio.get_attribute('id'))
    radio.click()
```

It correctly selects the elements in question. However, it does not get selected nor does it yield any obvious errors. Can we use `.click()` to select radio buttons here? Is this some kind of handler problem?

Comment: Figure this out Jan? How bout starting a bounty?

Comment: Also, how is it possible that my profile has a `reach` that is almost triple yours? I'm not trying to start a pissing match I'm just genuinely curious. Judging by your reputation you should have reached a zillion people by now.

Comment: @zelusp: I guess it's depending on the type of question you're asking. I'd reckon that `JSON` questions are generally reaching a broader audience, e.g. your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file/37757378#37757378

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].checked = true;",element)
```

You can also try by sending `ENTER` Key to the element.

Comment: Does not do the job.

Comment: @Jan I have gone through some of the articles and they says apply wait because sometimes element is not in the state to click.

Answer (score -2):

Try using  following Css selector:

```
        Actions action = new Actions(drive);

        action.moveToElement(drive.findElement( By.cssSelector("label > input[id^='M37_Q_']"))).build().perform();

        drive.findElement( By.cssSelector("label > input[id^='M37_Q_']")).click();
```

Comment: Does not do the job.

Comment: As stated, this is in `Python`, your code is for sth. else (probably `JS`).

Comment: ohh.. my bad, This code is for Java but you can try using selenium actions class in python if available.